# Error when setting attributes in Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I defined a function _set_thumbnail that attaches an attribute to an object.

```
   class StdImageField(ImageField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, width_field=None,
        height_field=None, sizes=None, **kwargs):

        self.sizes = sizes
        super(StdImageField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, width_field,
            height_field, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        """Call methods for generating all operations on specified signals"""
        super(StdImageField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        signals.post_save.connect(self.resize_image, sender=cls)
        signals.post_init.connect(self._set_thumbnail, sender=cls)

    def resize_image(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
        if getattr(instance, self.name):
            filename = getattr(instance, self.name).path
            shutil.copyfile(filename, '%s/%d-0.jpg' % (os.path.dirname(filename), instance._get_pk_val()))
            for i, size in enumerate(self.sizes):
                img = Image.open(filename)
                img = ImageOps.fit(img, size, method=Image.ANTIALIAS)
                new_filename = '%s/%d-%d.jpg' % (os.path.dirname(filename), instance._get_pk_val(), i + 1)
                img.save(new_filename, "JPEG", quality=100)

    def _set_thumbnail(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
        if getattr(instance, self.name):
            for i, size in enumerate(self.sizes):
                setattr(getattr(instance, self.name), 'image%d' % (i + 1), '%s%d-%d.jpg' % ('s/', instance._get_pk_val(), i + 1))
```

It works flawlessly through Django admin. However, while using it through front-end i get an eror:

TypeError  ( %d format: a number is required, not NoneType )

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: check `instance._get_pk_val()` always return a value(number)?

Comment: I think `instance` hasn't been saved to DB, so it doesn't have `pk`.

Comment: have you tried using pdb? Stick `pdb.set_trace()` in there and follow through to see what the variables are, or split the line up so the error gets narrowed down.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I guess u r right. instance._get_pk_val() is lost in the process. Could you please give a hint on how to address it? In the code below first I save and image, later - try to address it and the error is thrown... (instance is not saved somehow)

Comment: You connect the function to `post_init` signal. There is no guarantee something has been saved there. May be you should connect to `post_save`?